# ERC - modify incoming messages

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using the below elisp code to modify incoming messages from ERC

```
(defun my-modify (msg)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "abc" "xyz" msg))
(add-hook 'erc-insert-modify-hook 'my-modify)
```

I am getting the following error

```
error in process filter: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (msg) 
(replace-regexp-in-string "abc" "xyz" msg)), 0
```

Comment: +1 to counter the drive-by downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what's wrong in my previous code, but I was able to modify incoming messages using this code (from http://mwolson.org/projects/emacs-config/erc-init.el)

```
(defun my-modify (proc parsed)
  (let ((msg (erc-response.contents parsed)))
    (when (stringp msg)
      (setf (erc-response.contents parsed)
            (erc-replace-regexp-in-string "abc" "xyz" msg))
      nil)))
(add-hook 'erc-server-PRIVMSG-functions 'my-modify)
```

This works as expected, but what I really wanted was to strip away a particular nick and display only the message. However I don't think that's possible at ERC level. Rather I will have to try it at the buffer level.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently functions invoked from `erc-insert-modify-hook` do not get the incoming message as an argument, like your code expects.

Quoting http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ErcHooks we see:

> This hook is run after the actual text is inserted. While it runs, the buffer is narrowed to the inserted text using narrow-to-region. Thus, you can use (point-min) and (point-max) to determine start and end of the inserted text on the modify hooks.

So you should replace in the current buffer instead.